# Make bullets for "space invader"

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make projectiles for my ship in my version of space invader. I think the only thing that doesen't work right now is displaying all the projectile because I don't know how, and that's why i tried using blit which didn't work. Also I want to delay the timings between each projectile but i'm not sure how to do that. 
So far this is the most advanced screen-related program i've done.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.originalImage = pygame.image.load("ship.png")
        self.image = self.originalImage
        self.xposition = 480
        self.yposition = 450
        self.speed = 1

class Projectile():
    def __init__(self):
        self.originalImage = pygame.image.load("shot.png")
        self.image = self.originalImage
        self.xposition = player.xposition
        self.yposition = player.yposition
        self.speed = 1


size = width, height = 960, 540
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
background = 0, 0, 0
player = Player()
projectile = Projectile()
projectiles = []
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

while True:
    screen.fill(background)

    for projectile in projectiles:
        if projectile.yposition < height:
            projectile.yposition -= projectile.speed
        else:
            projectiles.pop(projectiles.index(projectile))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    if (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]) == True:
        player.xposition += player.speed
    if (keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]) == True:
        player.xposition -= player.speed
    if (keys[pygame.K_SPACE] or keys[pygame.K_w] or keys[pygame.K_UP]) == True:
        projectiles.append(projectile)

    for projectile in projectiles:
        screen.blit(projectile.image, (projectile.xposition, projectile.yposition))

    screen.blit(player.image, ((player.xposition, player.yposition)))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I edited the code after the comment but still nothing moves...

Comment: `screen.blit(projectile.image, (projectile.xposition, projectile.yposition))`. But note, the player and the projectiles have the same position. You can't "see" the projectiles, because they player covers them.

Comment: I edited the code as you recommended, and I have a line that makes the projectiles go up and it did kinda work, but not more than once every time I start the game. Atm nothing moves and no projectiles shoot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite). Derive `Projectile` from `Sprite`. A `Sprite` should have the attributes `.image` and `.rect`. Add a method which moves the `Projectile` and [`kill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill)s it when it goes out of bounds. e.g:

```py
class Projectile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 
        self.originalImage = pygame.image.load("shot.png")
        self.image = self.originalImage
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (player.xposition, player.yposition))
        self.speed = 1

    def move(self):
        self.rect.y -= self.speed
        if self.rect.y < 0:
            self.kill()
```

Create a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) to contain the projectiles:

```py
projectiles = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

The Sprites in a `Group` can be drawn by [`.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw).

```py
projectiles.draw(screen)
```

Every time when the player fires a bullet, then a new instance of bullet has to be created and be add to the Group of bullets. I recommend to us the keyboard events for that:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    # [...]

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE or event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_UP: 
            projectiles.add(Projectile())
```

The states of the keys (`keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()`) have to be evaluated in the main application loop. The speed of the application can be controlled by the [`pygame.time.Clock()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock):

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.originalImage = pygame.image.load("ship.png")
        self.image = self.originalImage
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (480, 450))
        self.speed = 1

class Projectile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 
        self.originalImage = pygame.image.load("shot.png")
        elf.image = self.originalImage
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = player.rect.center)
        self.speed = 1

    def move(self):
        self.rect.y -= self.speed
        if self.rect.y < 0:
            self.kill()


size = width, height = 960, 540
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
background = 0, 0, 0
player = Player()
projectiles = pygame.sprite.Group()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(120)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
           if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE or event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_UP: 
              projectiles.add(Projectile())

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]) == True:
        player.rect.x += player.speed
    if (keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]) == True:
        player.rect.x -= player.speed

    for projectile in projectiles:
        projectile.move()

    screen.fill(background)
    projectiles.draw(screen)
    screen.blit(player.image, player.rect.topleft)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is the problem:

- Nothing is moving because `pygame.key.get_pressed()` is outside the game loop, ie you only check the state of keys at startup.
- You must create a new `Projectile` instance each time you shoot, otherwise you'd be able to shoot only once.
- To make the projectiles appear properly, you must blit the player sprite first, and then blit the projectiles, otherwise the player sprite will cover them.
- To code in a delay between shots, store the shooting cooldown in a variable (preferably a `player` attribute), which you set to some positive value each time you shoot and decrement each turn.
- You use `sys.exit()` but you haven't imported `sys`, which makes your game crash during exiting. Alternatively you can `raise SystemExit` instead, which does exactly the same thing as sys.exit() and doesn't need any imports.

Here is the corrected code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.originalImage = pygame.image.load("ship.png")
        self.image = self.originalImage
        self.xposition = 480
        self.yposition = 450
        self.speed = 1
        self.attack_cooldown = 0   # variable to store shooting cooldown

class Projectile():
    def __init__(self):
        self.originalImage = pygame.image.load("shot.png")
        self.image = self.originalImage
        self.xposition = player.xposition
        self.yposition = player.yposition
        self.speed = 1


size = width, height = 960, 540
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
background = 0, 0, 0
player = Player()
projectiles = []

while True:
    screen.fill(background)

    # decrement the current shooting cooldown
    if player.attack_cooldown > 0:
        player.attack_cooldown -= 1

    for projectile in projectiles:
        if projectile.yposition < height:
            projectile.yposition -= projectile.speed
        else:
            projectiles.pop(projectiles.index(projectile))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            raise SystemExit   # does the same thing as sys.exit() but you don't need to import sys

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()   # put this in the game loop

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]:
        player.xposition += player.speed
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]:
        player.xposition -= player.speed
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] or keys[pygame.K_w] or keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        if player.attack_cooldown == 0:   # shoot only when not on cooldown
            projectiles.append(Projectile())   # shoot a new projectile instead of the one you already shot
            player.attack_cooldown = 100   # add shooting cooldown, the number can be any positive integer you want

    # blit the player first
    screen.blit(player.image, ((player.xposition, player.yposition)))
    for projectile in projectiles:
        screen.blit(projectile.image, (projectile.xposition, projectile.yposition))

    pygame.display.flip()
```